# Cakephp query doesn't render correct data

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm totally new in cakephp and fetching problem at the time of query to render data

I tried this to find out categories/warehouses table info but failed..

```
    $cart_products = $this->Order->OrdersProduct->find('all', array(
                'fields' => array('*'),
                'contain' => array('Category'),
                'joins' => array(
                    array(
                        'table' => 'products',
                        'alias' => 'Product',
                        'type' => 'LEFT',
                        'conditions' => array('Product.id = OrdersProduct.product_id')
                    ),
                    array(
                        'table' => 'orders',
                        'alias' => 'Order',
                        'type' => 'LEFT',
                        'conditions' => array('Order.id = OrdersProduct.order_id')
                    )
                ),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Order.store_id' => $store_id,
                    'Order.order_status' => 'in_cart'
                )
            ));

I need the result something like this...
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [OrdersProduct] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [order_id] => 1
                    [product_id] => 16
                    [qty] => 10
                    [created] => 2013-10-24 08:04:33
                    [modified] => 2013-10-24 08:04:33
                )

            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 16
                    [part] => 56-987xyz
                    [title] => iPhone 5 battery
                    [description] => iPhone 5c description
                    [wholesale_price] => 4
                    [retail_price] => 8
                    [purchase_cost] => 2
                    [sort_order] => 
                    [Category] => array(
                           [id] => 1,
                           [name] => Iphone 5
                    )
                    [Warehouse] => array(
                           [id] => 1,
                           [name] => Warehouse1
                    )
                    [weight] => 
                    [created] => 2013-10-22 12:14:57
                    [modified] => 2013-10-22 12:14:57
                )
      )
)
```

How can I find this? Can anybody help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing joins in the query, you should be setting up relationships between each of these tables in their model file. When these relationships are created, the relevant data will be gathered by simply doing a find on the one table as normal.

The relationships are simple to setup, but are specific to your table structure so I recommend reading about them here and deciding for yourself which relationships are needed between which tables:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Answer (score 0):

Define proper model associations to your tables and try something like this:

```
$this->Order->Behaviors->attach('containable');
$cart_products = $this->Order->OrdersProduct->find('all', array(                
                'contain' => array('Product', 'Product.Category', 'Product.Warehouse'),                
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Order.store_id' => $store_id,
                    'Order.order_status' => 'in_cart'
                )
            ));
```

Reference for Model Associations: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Reference for Containable Behavior: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html